# Rails 3 and youtube-g

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Pls can anyone help me. Any time i configure my youtube-g and i put in the videos url it gives me this =

```
 <strong>AJAX with jQuery: The Beginning:</strong><br/><div id="d99acf13bf1a1da5a4249d3435d5001544c40d70"><object width="425" height="350">  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/ts6GTNOO4nY&feature=youtube_gdata_player"></param>  <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ts6GTNOO4nY&feature=youtube_gdata_player" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="425" height="350"></embed> </object> </div>
```

and it does not display the video. the url i put in for this instance is:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ts6GTNOO4nY

. pls what can i do

Comment: wideos? Not sure what that is. Nothing really stands out why that should embed should not work.

Comment: i do not know if it is because i am running it from my local host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the youtube_it gem, not the youtube-g one

in your Gemfile

```
gem 'youtube_it', :git => 'git://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it.git'
```

if you want to use the git version of the gem.